# Can't get available DrmEngines android

Tags: android, android-drm

I'm using **DrmManagerClient** to get available **DRMengines** like this:

```
DrmManagerClient mDrmManager = new DrmManagerClient(context);
   String[] engines = mDrmManager.getAvailableDrmEngines();
```

With some devices like **huawei** or **honor**, `getAvailableDrmEngines` returns `0` but the device can support *widevine* because I tested it with DRM Info App. What did I do wrong, or what did I miss?

Answer (score 0):

Probably your device doesn't support the classic DRM apis. Maybe try with the new [MediaDrm](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaDrm.html#getMaxSecurityLevel()) api.

I haven't tried this myself but what I am expecting is Widevine L1 should return 6 (default) or [SECURITY_LEVEL_HW_SECURE_ALL](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaDrm#SECURITY_LEVEL_HW_SECURE_ALL) while L3 should report [SECURITY_LEVEL_SW_SECURE_DECODE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaDrm.html#SECURITY_LEVEL_SW_SECURE_DECODE) or [SECURITY_LEVEL_SW_SECURE_CRYPTO](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaDrm.html#SECURITY_LEVEL_SW_SECURE_CRYPTO).

The values returned might change but you get the idea.

widevine L3 vs widevine L1:

- L1: all content processing and cryptography operations are handled
  inside a Trusted Execution Environment (TEE)
- L2: only cryptography
  operations are handled inside a TEE
- L3: content processing and
  cryptography operations are (intentionally) handled outside of a TEE,
  or the device doesn’t support a TEE.